# Mongoose.js - dont know why my conditional if array is bigger than [0] doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm using MERN & im struggling with the if statement as below.

```
  ...
    const checkHistroy = await (Schema.findOne({
        userId: user.id
    }).find({
        "History.0": {
            "$exists": true
        }
    }))

    try {

        if (checkHistory) {
            console.log('you cannot send any more request')
        } else {
            res.status(200).send(postData);
        }


    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).send(err);
    }
    });
```

I'm basically trying to limit the users array to be no more longer than 1 (i.e only have index of 0). I've tested my `const checkHistory` but the If statement I've wrote returns the response as if theirs no condition to abide. My question is, am i doing something obviously wrong or does mongo/mongoose have its own syntactical way of executing conditionals. Help and/or advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set a condition on array length, you should do the following:

```
if (checkHistory.length >= 1) {
     console.log('you cannot send any more request')
}
```

Comment: this helped a little as I restructered things a little and the If Statement works but when i replace my `false` part of if statement and replace the .log with my send response, it fires off even when it shouldn't. any reason why?

Comment: Nevermind, got it working. I had to place my async await on my variables out of global and inside the IF statement. thanks for the nudge. JZK